# Как на CSS сделать текст в виде обводки со свечением?

Tags: css

Есть такая картинка, на которой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли на чистом CSS сверстать такой текст?
Чтобы была обводка и свечение, как на картинке.

Comment: можно сделать обводку text-shadow: 3px 0 #a54cd9, -2px 0 #a54cd9, 0 2px #a54cd9, 0 -2px #a54cd9, 1px 1px #a54cd9, -1px -1px #a54cd9, 0px -1px #a54cd9, -1px 1px #a54cd9;  а со свечением не уверена, попробовать делать абсолютно позиционированный текст с черным колором и делать ему обводку прозрачную сиреневую, больше ничего не приходит в голову. Либо старым добрым способом свг или пнг

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть более простой и удобный способ сделать это используя возможности webkit, предлагаю такое решение:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(19, 18, 24);
}

.glowing-text {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--color);
  text-shadow: var(--color) 0 0 15px;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: Arial, 'Segeo UI';
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<span class="glowing-text" style="--color: rgb(31, 198, 234);">БОНУС<br> 100 FS</span>

<span class="glowing-text" style="--color: rgb(212, 17, 245);">150%</span>
```

#### Объяснение

Сначала сделаем саму обводку текста, цвет обводки берётся из переменной `--color` которая указывается в inline-стилях (Стили указанные в HTML, в атрибуте `style`). Далее делаем сам эффект свечения, он делается благодаря свойству `text-shadow` в котором мы просто делаем тень размытой, цвет также взят с той же переменной. После чего мы делаем цвет текста прозрачным чтобы можно было увидеть фон сзади текста. После всё по вкусу, но если требуется объяснение, то вот: сделал текст более гладким с помощью шрифтов `Arial` и `Segoe UI` и сам текст большим (65 пикселей).

Comment: Я уже нашел такое же решение ранее :-) Спасибо, это то, что нужно.

Comment: @FrontEnder007 всё возможно, я его и до этого писал для codepen :p

Answer (score 4):

Можно на CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #1c2555;
}

.text-light {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgba(28, 37, 85);
  
  --os: 2px; /* outline size */
  --osc: #fff; /* outline color */
  --osb: 20px; /* outline shadow blur */
  --osbc: rgba(255,255,255,.75); /* outline shadow blur color */
  
  text-shadow:
     calc(var(--os) * 1.306562965)   calc(var(--os) * .541196101) 0 var(--osc),
     calc(var(--os) * 1.414213562)                             0  0 var(--osc),
     calc(var(--os) * 1.306562965)  calc(var(--os) * -.541196101) 0 var(--osc),
               calc(var(--os) * 1)           calc(var(--os) * -1) 0 var(--osc),
      calc(var(--os) * .541196101) calc(var(--os) * -1.306562965) 0 var(--osc),
                                0  calc(var(--os) * -1.414213562) 0 var(--osc),
     calc(var(--os) * -.541196101) calc(var(--os) * -1.306562965) 0 var(--osc),
              calc(var(--os) * -1)           calc(var(--os) * -1) 0 var(--osc),
    calc(var(--os) * -1.306562965)  calc(var(--os) * -.541196101) 0 var(--osc),
    calc(var(--os) * -1.414213562)                             0  0 var(--osc),
    calc(var(--os) * -1.306562965)   calc(var(--os) * .541196101) 0 var(--osc),
              calc(var(--os) * -1)            calc(var(--os) * 1) 0 var(--osc),
     calc(var(--os) * -.541196101)  calc(var(--os) * 1.306562965) 0 var(--osc),
                                0   calc(var(--os) * 1.414213562) 0 var(--osc),
      calc(var(--os) * .541196101)  calc(var(--os) * 1.306562965) 0 var(--osc),
               calc(var(--os) * 1)            calc(var(--os) * 1) 0 var(--osc),
     0 0 var(--osb) var(--osbc);
}

.text-lignt--color-1 {
  --osc: #20bde0;
  --osbc: rgba(32,189,224, .75);
  margin-right: 1ch;
}

.text-lignt--color-2 {
  --osc: #bc23d6;
  --osbc: rgba(188,35,214, .75);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-light text-lignt--color-1">БОНУС<br>100 FS</div>
<div class="text-light text-lignt--color-2">150%</div>
```

Но лучше такое сделать на SVG, предварительно конвертировать текст в кривые.

---

По просьбе комментатора делаю описание кода)

Основная масса кода - `text-shadow`, много параметров, т.к. они создают обводку вокруг текста, несмотря на то, что есть как `-webkit-text-stroke`, но оно полностью не поддерживается [IE](https://caniuse.com/text-stroke), если требуется его поддержка, то придётся костылить засчёт `text-shadow`.

Первая строчка `text-shadow` просто белая подложка, чтобы прозрачный цвет не сливался с обводной.
Со второй до предпоследней - специально высчитанный мной код, чтобы сделать обводку более плотной, там каждый цвет располагается на определённый угол, кол-во строк == кол-ву сегментов (для примера скрин - где текст имеет обводку из [4х](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bj1Y.png) теней (4х сегментов), [12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdrHs.png) и [40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuVpL.png). Но в данном коде выше, используется 16 сегментов и этот параметр не изменяется. Код генерировался тут ([Миксин outline text для Stylus](https://codepen.io/de-minov/pen/NWzjRrx))).
Последняя строчка отвечает уже за свечение текста.

CSS переменные используются для удобной "кастомизации" всех значений:
`--os` - размер "обводки"
`--osc` - цвет обводки
`--osb` - размер размытия свечения
`--osbc` - цвет свечения

Каждый параметр может быть общим для всех и\или изменятся для конкретного элемента.

Comment: Было бы неплохо в вашем ответе предоставить объяснение, так, не совсем понятно что и как работает.

Comment: @ΝNL993, спасибо, дополнил)